# TypeError: string indices must be integers datetime

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

I'm trying to convert a datetime, but I can't figure out how to get my string to be an integer. I've tried adding in [0] after (entry["created_at"] but not luck

**Code:**

`$`for item in data:

```
   `$` convertedTweet = {}

for entry in item:
   convertedTweet["created_at"] = item["created_at"]
   fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
   temp = datetime.strptime(entry['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
   print temp.strftime(fmt)
```

**Error:**

```
temp = datetime.strptime(entry['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `I can't figure out how to get my string to be an integer` what about `int(string)`?

Comment: item is converted tweet, updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `item` is a dictionary ( as you do this - `item["created_at"]` , and it does not error out for you ) .

If so, when you loop through the dictionary as -

```
for entry in item:
```

`entry` represents the keys in the dictionary, which most probably are strings. So when you try to do - `entry['created_at']` - it errors out as you are trying to use string indices for strings , which is not possible.

It does not look like you need loop at all, you can directly access  - `item["created_at"]` - to get the datetime. Example -

```
convertedTweet["created_at"] = item["created_at"] 
temp = datetime.strptime(item["created_at"],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
print temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Comment: I think I did. This was my first post. Thanks again for help